# How to Mark multiple Files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I mark more than one file in Visual Studio Code's Explorer view? 
It is a bit painful to ask such a question, but the answer may help others too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is currently not possible :(

Vote for it on [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8062287-select-multiple-files-in-explore) and the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1023).

Comment: Use the **thumbs up** [reaction](https://github.com/blog/2119-add-reactions-to-pull-requests-issues-and-comments) (or another one) on the [**first** issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1023#issue-120463840)

Comment: i just can't believe, sometimes microsoft goes very very bad on UX.